# How to access Implicit Styles set for the controls in `.NET8`

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

I have a custom control and would like to retrieve the style that is implicitly set for use within my control. However, due to the SetterSpecificity protection level, I am unable to access it.

I have achieved this as follows.

This was working as expected in '.Net7'.

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:CustomButton">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Bisque" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <local:CustomButton
                Text="Hello World!!"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</ContentPage>
```

```xml
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       
    }

    public class CustomButton : Button
    {
        public CustomButton()
        {
            this.Clicked += CustomButton_Clicked;
        }

        private void CustomButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dynamicResources = (Dictionary<BindableProperty, string>)typeof(Element)?.GetRuntimeProperties()?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DynamicResources")?.GetValue(this);
            var key = dynamicResources?.Keys.FirstOrDefault();
            var style = (Style)this.GetValue(key);
        }
    }
}
```

However, in .NET 8, it's not functioning as expected. Facing the following issue related to SetterSpecificity.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are trying to get the Implicit style shouldn't it apply by default to your custom control why do you need to explicitly apply it?

Comment: I have a custom control, and I want to check whether the implicit style is set or not. If the implicit style is not set, I want to apply the default style. So, I need to obtain the implicit style.

Comment: Yes, it is just the case as you said. For this problem, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose). Thanks for your support and feedback for Maui.